# Encrypted disk does not accept password on Mac

Tags: backup, encryption

I made an encrypted backup disk, and I've entered the exact correct password a few times, but system does not accept it. Any idea what is going on? Strange on other backup disk behaves in the same way. One of them is a WD disk. Is it something wrong with my Mac?

Comment: I'd say you're probably not typing the right password, even though you think you are.

Comment: Earlier I started reparation a USB drive, and that stucked, and I think Disk Utility get corrupted. Then I restarted Mac, and afterwards password was accepted.

Answer (score 1):

A few possibilities:

> 1. cap-locks are inadvertently on now, or when you made the password
> 2. you cut-paste the password from a 'secret' file, but the password has an extra space at the end?
> 3. You are typing an 'oh' instead of a 'zero' when you look at your hand-written notes?
> 4. You have changed your 'default keyboard' from U.S. to British, or something odd like that?

Just my two cents.